# What's the fastest way to get time in am/pm?

Tags: python-2.7

What is the fastest Python's equivalent to C#'s `DateTime.Now.ToString("h tt")`?

If the time is now 0905h, it will give `9 AM`.  If the time is now 1526h it will give `3 PM`.  (Assuming some English locale.)

I have seen a number of examples but they are too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) either from [`time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#module-time):

```
In [4]: import time

In [5]: time.strftime("%I %p")
Out[5]: '10 AM'
```

Or [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#) objects:

```
In [14]: from datetime import datetime

In [15]: today = datetime.now()

In [16]: today
Out[16]: datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 17, 10, 32, 10, 161824)

In [17]: today.strftime("%I %p")
Out[17]: '10 AM'
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is this doable also in the `datetime` module?  I am currently using `datetime` to manipulate some other variables of time.

Comment: +1, although if you want it _exactly_ the same, you may want to `lstrip('0')` at the end to give `9 AM` instead of `09 AM`.